# Catch coredll.dll native exception in netcf C#

Tags: exception, windows-mobile, native

in a closed dll, i've sometime this exception:

[image]

Is possible to catch it?

Windows mobile, netcf 3.5, C#
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's an access violation exception. You can try the [SEHException class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception.aspx), but I'm not entirely sure if that's available in the compact framework.

Either way, you'll be better off fixing the issue that's causing the exception.